# cppcms session in async. mode

Tags: c++, session, asynchronous, cppcms

I use this code to run async. server:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  cppcms::service service(argc, argv);
  booster::intrusive_prt<gameServer> c = new gameServer(service);
  service.applications_pool().mount(c);
  service.run();
}
```

And in gameServer class I have this codes:

```
session().reset_session();
session()["username"] = "admin";
session().save();
...
if(!session().load())
  std::cerr<<" session doesn't load";
```

When I compile and run program, `session doesn't load` message shows. If I replace the `main` function with sync. server and remove `session().load()` and `session().save()`, there is no error and `session["username"]` can be shown.

Here is my configuration file

```
{
  ...
  "file_server" : { "enable" : true, "document_root" : "." },
  "session : 
  {
    "expire" : "browser",
    "timeout" : 604800,
    "location" : "server",
    "server" : { "storage" : "files" }
  }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `session().load()` should be first statement in session handling of asynchronous applications

You don't really need to check the status.

After you change the session you call save.

You don't call "load()" at the end